# Set a word in a text file and replace or delete its value using Batchfile (User Input)

Tags: batch-file

I got an error when i run my code. 
Its like i got a textfile in C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\ComOrg
and in, it has a sentence in there and i need to change the value of that word

Like:
Run:
*The word inside the textfile here*
Enter an input [R]-Replace [D]-Delete :

if  i click R

Enter the word that you want to replace :

lets say i type "Word"
and if i type the word

Enter the word: *the word the you will replace*

Output = Change the value of the word in a sentence

Here's my code:

```
@echo off 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

SET /P _inputname= Please enter "1" to view the text : 
    if "%_inputname%"=="1" type "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\ComOrg\Sentence.txt "
echo off

echo off
SET /P _name= Please enter an Input [A]-ERASE [B]-DELETE : 

    IF "%_inputname%"=="A" SET /P _inputname= Pick a word the you want to replace : 
        IF  "%_name%"=="love" SET /P _inputname= Type the word : 
            echo I %_name% batch script 
                @echo I %_name% batch script > C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\ComOrg\Sentence.txt 


endlocal
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow it's hard to answer if you don't post the code! Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to see how to create an example!

Answer (score 0):

for replacing parts of the string, use the `set` command (see `set /?` for info):

```
set "string=The mouse eats the cat"
echo %string%
echo %string:mouse=dog%
```

To replace with variables, you need [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082):

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "string=The mouse eats the cat"
set old=cat
set new=cheese
echo !string:%old%=%new%!
```

Comment: Yes. Thank you for the code. but i already used that code. I just could not do the user input on how to replace the word in a text file.

Comment: Can you do me for user input in replacing a word in a text file?

Comment: to get user input, use `set /p`. For search/replace in a textfile, see the articles below "Related" at the right side. The [first one] seems to fit perfectly.

Comment: Yes i use it already. But i think my code has a problem. Can you do me a code? I'll show you mine and i don't know what's my error

Comment: run it without `echo off`, so it shows you exactly what it does and where it fails.